# Einstein $E=mc^2$ equation what if we found an element energy?

Tags: special-relativity, energy, visible-light, mass-energy, speed

I started research in time travel  idea soon  and iam asking what if there exist an element that gives energy equals to c^2  in the equation  is the mass of this element is 1 ( i don't know the unit of mass in the equation )    is my question possible or its impossible  , iam new  to einstein relativity i started  research in it soon

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the equation $E=mc^2$ the units are generally SI units and here the mass $m$ is in kilograms or kg. Notice that numerous things can have a mass of 1kg but you’d just need different volumes of that substance. A small iron block can be 1kg and have an energy of $c^2$ and so can a big bag of 1 kg cotton have the energy of $c^2$. Hence by no logic can some object be known as element 1 as the object is not uniquely defined if it has a mass of 1 kg.

In reality we *do* define an *element 1* by the number of protons(known formally as atomic number)it has(as the proton has a fixed mass/energy density as we say) and that element is called **hydrogen** and so on for other *elements* and they indeed will have a fixed energy at rest which is given by the original equation.